# VkWin32SurfaceCreateInfoKHR not available after specifying extensions with glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions

Tags: c++, glfw, vulkan

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 Community with C++17 and Vulkan SDK 1.2.148.1

```
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

//other vulkan stuff here

VkInstance instance;
uint32_t count;
VkInstanceCreateInfo createInfo{};

createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
createInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions(&count);
createInfo.enabledExtensionCount = count;
createInfo.enabledLayerCount = 0;
vkCreateInstance(&createInfo, nullptr, &instance)
```

After creating the instance, `VkWin32SurfaceCreateInfoKHR` is still not available. The code fails at:

```
VkWin32SurfaceCreateInfoKHR createInfo{};
```

Full code on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/NF1a2wzW). The error is on line 110.

Comment: I know there are other ways to get VkWin32SurfaceCreateInfoKHR to work but I was just wondering why glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VkWin32SurfaceCreateInfoKHR`is platform specific for windows, so in order to use it you need to define `VK_USE_PLATFORM_WIN32_KHR` somewhere in your project.

Comment: shouldn’t glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions handle that

Comment: @YEpd Nope. GLFW doc: "The VK_USE_PLATFORM_*_KHR macros do not need to be defined for the Vulkan part of GLFW to work. **Define them only if you are using these extensions directly.**"